# Viewing recently edited etherpads

Tags: sql, mysql, open-source, etherpad

*Prescript:  The amazing [etherpad](http://etherpad.com) was recently open sourced.  Get it here: http://code.google.com/p/etherpad.  This is the first question that I know of on StackOverflow about the etherpad code.  If you're part of the etherpad open source community, you might want to subscribe to [the RSS feed for questions tagged 'etherpad'](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=etherpad) just in case this catches on!*

My actual question, which assumes you have etherpad installed on your own server:

First, here's a query to view recently edited pads:

```
SELECT id,lastWriteTime,creationTime,headRev 
  FROM PAD_SQLMETA ORDER BY lastWriteTime, headRev;
```

Or, if you want to run it from a unix prompt:

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWD etherpad -e "select id,lastWriteTime,creationTime,headRev 
  from PAD_SQLMETA order by lastWriteTime, headRev"
```

That's handy, however `lastWriteTime` actually gets updated every time someone so much as views a pad in their browser.  I'd rather sort the pads by when they were actually last edited.  There's probably a fancy SQL query involving a join with another table that would show actual last edit time.  Does anyone know what that is?  Alternatively, you could have a script that notices when headRev changes but that doesn't seem like the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't quite figured out the answer to my original question but I wrote a script that achieves something similar.
It's main purpose is to export plain text versions of all my pads and store them on my laptop.
As a side effect it shows me which pads have changed and lets me see a diff since the last exported version.
It also shows which ones were newly created.

First, create the following script, `padlist.pl`, on the server that hosts your etherpad instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$list = `mysql -u root -pPASSWD etherpad -e 
         "select id from PAD_SQLMETA order by lastWriteTime DESC, headRev DESC"`;

$list =~ s/^id\s*\n//s;  # get rid of the column header mysql adds.
print $list;
```

Then run the following script, `fetchall.pl`, on your local machine.
It will suck down snapshots of all your pads and tell you which ones have changed and which have newly appeared.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use LWP::Simple qw(get);
$| = 1;  # autoflush.
$server = "server.com"; # the server that hosts your etherpad instance.

$pads = `ssh $server etherpad/padlist.pl`;
@padlist = split(/\s+/, $pads);

$neednewline = 0; # printing "." for each pad where nothing to be done.
for(@padlist) {
  $ep = $_;
  $localfile = "$ep.txt";
  if(-e $localfile) { 
    $localexists = 1; 
    $localcontent = do {local (@ARGV,$/) = $localfile; <>};
  } else { $localexists = 0; }
  $livecontent = get("http://$server/ep/pad/export/$ep/latest?format=txt");
  if($livecontent ne $localcontent) {
    if($neednewline) { print "\n";  $neednewline = 0; }
    if($localexists) { 
      print "CHANGED: $ep\n"; 
      open(F, ">prev/$localfile") or die "Probably need to create 'prev' dir.";
      print F $localcontent;
      close(F);
    } else { print "NEW:     $ep\n"; }
    open(F, ">$localfile") or die;
    print F $livecontent;
    close(F);
  } else {
    print ".";
    $neednewline = 1;
} }
```

To see a diff of pad foo since the last time I fetched it:

```
diff prev/foo.txt foo.txt
```